# Select From wpdb - Author/User Directory page

Tags: database, users, author, wpdb, select

I am working on a wordpress site where I have created a directory page(authors.php) that lists all users and certain author meta.

It works fine however I am trying to figure out how to only show users that have the required author meta filled out.

I've tried many different things but have not been able to achieve what I need. Here is my code

```
<?php
    $order = 'user_nicename';
$users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY $order"); // query users

    foreach($users as $user) : // start users' profile "loop"
    ?>
```

Everything else I try does not return any results. Is there a way to only select users with specific author meta fields filled out? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off to use [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) which returns an array of

```
<?php
// get all users, regardless of roll.  If you do need to restrict by
// role you can use the `role` argument: get_users(array('role' => 'author'));
$uses = get_users(array('orderby' => 'nicename'));

foreach ($users as $user) {
   // do stuff with $user, will have all the usual stuff, ID, user_email, etc
   echo '<p>', esc_html($user->ID), '</p>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `all_with_meta` argument for the `fields` argument of `get_users` and get an array of [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) objects back:

```
<?php

$users = get_users(array('fields' => 'all_with_meta'));

foreach ($users as $user) {
   // $user will be a WP_User object.
}
```

> Is there a way to only select users with specific author meta fields filled out?

You can do this with get users as well! Just use the `meta_query` argument, which looks the same as [`WP_Query`'s meta_query argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
<?php
$users = get_users(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key'   => 'whatever_your_meta_key_is',
            'value' => 'the_meta_value_you_want',
        )
     ),
));

foreach ($users as $user) {
    // do stuff with $user
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However Im having some trouble getting things to work. Here's what I have - `<?php 
$args  = array(
  'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => 'first_name' // the meta field (or key) we want to target
    )
));
$users = get_users($args);
foreach ($users as $user) : ?> //my content <?php
    endforeach; // end of the users' profile 'loop'
    ?>`

Comment: Either Im not understanding correctly or get_users is just not working for me. Is there anyway to do modify my original code to only show users with specific custom fields?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. There was a conflict caused by the plugin Profile Builder Pro.